# open source in PHP

Tags: php, open-source

Is there a site like codeplex just for PHP?

Basically a site for volunteers that wants to learn and code together. I want to develop a project, but I need someone to help me out.. don't know where to find this help.

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com (*takes tongue out of cheek*) ;-)

Comment: well..you have to pay to put it there...

Answer (score 2):

We have PECL:

http://pecl.php.net/

and PEAR:

http://pear.php.net/

But you'll find plenty of open source PHP code on Sourceforge, Github, etc.

Comment: I am kind of looking for a place where we can hire teams to work on a project voluntarily, as in codeplex.. not just repository

Comment: How are they being hired if it's voluntary?

Comment: hired voluntarily... just like codeplex.. hired to learn

Answer (score 0):

There are several site which used by PHP developer to host their code:

1. [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/)
2. [Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aPHP)
3. [Github](https://github.com/languages/PHP)
4. [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net)